# Error when changing dynamic array size in UFT

Tags: vba, hp-uft

I am trying to change the dynamic array.
Initially create an empty array, then add 1 before every time I need to add an item to an array.

```
Dim PegSubTot()
for i = 1 to end
If value found then
ReDim Preserve PegSubTot(Ubound(PegSubTot) + 1)
PegSubTot(i) = value
endif
next
```

Comment: You need to initialize the array first. The `UBound` fails the first time through the loop because it's never been defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the array size before you can change it:

```
Dim PegSubTot   ' declare as variable
for i = 1 to end ' presuming end is set somewhere?
    If value found then
        If IsArray(PegSubTot) Then ' check if it's an array
            ReDim Preserve PegSubTot(Ubound(PegSubTot) + 1) ' If it is, extend array by 1
        Else
            ReDim PegSubTot(0) ' If it's not redim as a one element array
        End If
        PegSubTot(UBound(PegSubTot)) = value ' Set highest element of array to value
    end if
next
```

On the first go around, the variable isn't an array so gets set to a one element array (you don't need preserve as it's the first value found).  On each subsequent loop, it is an array and so gets extended by one element each time, and the value is always placed in the `ubound` element of the array.

Let me know if this needs further clarification.